# How to write info to the file from bash script and see the result immediately?

Tags: bash, stdout, flush, buffering

I need help. I can't understand how I can write information to the file from bash script and see the result immediately.
For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PID=$$
echo "PID is $PID"
echo $PID > my_script.pid
echo "Sleeping..."
sleep 5
echo "Finished"
```

PID number appears in console immediately, but in the file I see it after script finished.
I have Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.
I tried a lot of stuff with flush buffering. NO result:(

Please, help!

Update.
My goal is to define if another instance of that script is still running. I decided to use pid file and condition:

```
PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
if ps -p $PID > /dev/null; then
     echo "script already running"
     exit 1
fi
```

Maybe there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You must be trying to read it too soon. To confirm that it's being written right away change the script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PID=$$
echo "PID is $PID"
echo "$PID written to file." >> my_script.pid
echo "Sleeping..."
sleep 5
echo "Finished"
```

Then run:

```
touch my_script.pid
tail -F my_script.pid &
./my_script.sh
```

The tail -F command will run on the background and will output whatever is written to my_script.pid shortly after it's written. The delay you see is on tail, once echo returns it is written.

Comment: Thanks fernan. Interesting decision. But I have another goal (see update)

Comment: Your new approach is not atomic. I guess you're writing the pid right after the if block. If another script gets to the cat statement before the first one writes the pid they both run! See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex for a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the article! It's very useful:)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misunderstanding. Actually it works fine. The problem in GUI tool (PyCharm) where I checked out file modification. It has interesting delay.
So when I check out previous PID from the same script it works fine:)
Thanks a lot fernan for help;)